# Making D3.js request JSON data to server.R and passing back data

Tags: d3.js, shiny

I am trying to get my front-end UI built with D3 to talk to server.R and get a JSON file to read instead of a static CSV as is currently done and working.

Just can't find a way to do it. Currently, the D3 portion of the code that reads the CSV (and works) looks like this:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "us.json")
    .defer(d3.csv, "aggregateKeystoneStates.csv", function(d) {
                dollarById.set(d.id, +d.dollar);
                textById.set(d.id, d.tooltiptext);
                })
    .await(ready);
```

Simply want it to pick up a JSON object instead from the server.R through input/output paradigm.

Sorry, I am too new to this stuff.